# Code style template not working for EJBs created using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, coding-style

I have a requirement to add copyright information for every new java file created, using Eclipse. So I updated the copyright information in "Java -> code style -> Code templates". This works fine when I create a new POJO class. But, the copyright information is not added automatically when I create new Servlets or EJBs.

Do I need to make anymore setting?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to [Eclipse Copyright Generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsecopyrigh/). It works fine with Eclipse 3.6. In the preferences (General > Copyright) you can define the template that should be used.

I am not sure if the header is included when you create a new file, but you can force the generation of the header by using: projects > apply copyright (it is also possible to suppress the old copyright header).